# Function inside selection condition in relational algebra

Tags: selection, conditional-statements, relational-algebra

Is it possible to use a user-defined function inside the selection condition in relational algebra?

**Ex:**

Can `<selection condition>` be: distance(x1, x2, y2, y2) < r

in `σ<selection condition>(R)`, where distance is a function that manipulates the values of attributes: x1, x2, y1 and y2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can write "a = b + c" too, right (hint : that is semantically the same as invoking a function plus(b,c) ) ?  So if it is allowed to invoke the PLUS function, what reasonable grounds would there be for ruling out some others (like your distance) ?

Well, it is a bit nonsensical to include nondeterministic functions (WHERE x = RANDOM()) but even there, it's unclear why it would have to be copped out ...

Technically speaking, a selection condition in RA (I mean, the selection condition "argument" to the RESTRICT operator) is like a lambda in the programming languages that support it, and a lambda can be really just any arbitrary function.

Implementation-wise, certain kinds of expressions are effectively ruled out, expressions that have side-effect updates (things like ++ increment and so), but that is not a concern if you are merely writing algebra expressions on paper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but according to definition for SELECT, those kind of formats are not allowed... but is it ok to disregard the constraints on the conditions???